# Updating Primefaces Component Value with function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

i want to update my component value evry 10 keyup , so I wrote the following code :

```
<h:body>
   //***************************JAVAScript function**************
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
 function fnc(){
                length=document.getElementById("aa").value.length;
                 if(length == 10)
                                {
                        document.getElementById("aa").value ="";

                                }

                }
```

```
<ui:composition template="commonLayout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <section id="main" class="column">
        <h4 class="alert_info">Scannez les bonbonnes puis cliquez sur
            enregistrer :</h4>
        <div class="Saut20px">

            <h:form id="form">
                <p:panel id="panel" header="Register">

                    <br />
                    <p:focus context="panel" />
                    <p:growl id="msgs"></p:growl>


                    <h:outputLabel value="Code Barre :" />

  //*****************call function in onComplete******
   <p:inputText id="aa" value="#{bonBonneManagedBean.sel}">
                        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="koko msgs" oncomplete="fnc()"
                            listener="#{bonBonneManagedBean.ajouterSelected(bonBonneManagedBean.sel)}" />
                    </p:inputText>
```

But the call does not work , if you can help me find the error, thank you in advance

Comment: The functional requirement is hard to understand. You want to submit *and clear out* the input value every 10 characters?

Comment: By the way, where did you learn about HTML and JS? The `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">` style is much like those found in prehistoric 90's tutorials/books. Try to make absolutely sure that you're reading up to date resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few problems here. First your comments, they probably just exist in this question, not in code, so I will not talk about them.

As **BalusC** wrote, you are using some strange form of defining script tag I must admit that I have never saw something like that. On the other hand you are using `section` tag, which is, as I know, HTML5 tag, and be prepared it will not work on browsers that don't support HTML5.

You created AJAX event that will be called on every `keyup` event on input field... well, that would be a lot of requests here. I suggest you to avoid that.

Your concrete problem is that you try to find element with id **aa**, but I must say that there is no such element. JSF concatenate IDs from naming containers so your input will have id like this `form:aa`, and maybe something more before, if there are more naming containers in surrounding page. You can inspect generated HTML code of your page, and see real id of input component. On the other case you can do something like:

```
<p:inputText id="aa" onkeyup="fnc(this)" value="#{bonBonneManagedBean.sel}"/>
```

With this solution remove `ajax` tag.

and change your `fnc` to:

```
function fnc(inputComponent)
{
  length = inputComponent.value.length;
  if(length == 10)
  {
    inputComponent.value = "";
  }
 }
```

At the end, I really think that you are playing with JSF and JavaScript, I really don't see any usability of this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I have a last question how can I call two functions: Java and Javascript with one KeyUp event on InputText

Answer (score 0):

Try using onkeyup attribute of inputtext component;

```
 <p:inputText id="aa" onkeyup="fnc()" value="#{bonBonneManagedBean.sel}">
```

Good Luck!

Comment: put an alert to your js? onkeyup attribute should call your js function and post your js console output pls

Comment: --js console  :
[15:57:13,602] ReferenceError: fnc is not defined @ http://localhost:8080/OxynordProjet/view/AjouterChargement.aspx:1

Comment: Thats mean fnc is called but not defined successfully, define it again just above the inputtext component and be sure is it defined

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i've other problem : --
[17:00:38,587] TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null @...

Comment: I prefer firebug plugin of firefox to debug your javascripts for like these situations.